# Who exactly is "he" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *[Braveheart (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart)*, Wallace motivates frightened Scottish men who ready to desert. Then he mounts up and
rides out with the Scottish nobles to meet the English contingent Cheltham:

> Cheltham: You are outmatched. You have no heavy cavalry. In two
> centuries, no  army has won...
>
> William Wallace: I'm not finished! Before we let you leave, your
> commander must cross that field, present himself before this army, put
> his head between his legs, and kiss his own arse.
>
> (Outraged Cheltham gallops back to his lines)
>
> Mornay: I'd say that was rather less cordial than **he** was used to.

Who exactly is "he" here?

Comment: Who could it be other than Cheltham? Could you [edit] your post to explain the confusion?

Comment: Have you actually seen who is talking to whom? Or are you just reading the script? Mornay is talking **about** Cheltham to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Braveheart.html), Cheltham is "outraged" - he is *used to* his opposing commanders being more cordial than Wallace has just been. Mornay is referring to Cheltham.

See also this helpful answer to a related question:

["I used to" and "I was used to" - What is the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131833/i-used-to-and-i-was-used-to-what-is-the-difference/131840)